# How to Debug Background Assets in macOS?

Tags: ios, wwdc, background-assets-framework

I attempted to utilize the Background Assets feature for an iOS app. While debugging, I employed the following command to trigger the installation event:

```
xcrun backgroundassets-debug -b <bundleID> -s --app-install -d <Device ID>
T
```

his command worked flawlessly on an iPhone.

However, when I attempted to trigger the installation event on a Mac, I encountered the following error message:

```
The requested device to send simulation events to is not available.
Verify that the device is connected to this Mac.
```

Please note that the `xcrun backgroundassets-debug -l` command only displays a list of connected devices.Mac is not listed in that list.

How to debug background assets in macos?